# Snowflake - Flatten JSON

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

i have a json like this:

```
{
    "col1": 5905,
    "col2": "4540",
    "col3": "23",
    "obj1": {
        "col4": 5905,
        "col5": 3100000000000,
        "col6": null
    },
    "obj2": [
        {
            "col7": null,
            "col8": 1
        },
        {
            "col7": null,
            "col8": 2
        }
    ],
    
    "obj3": {
        "col9": 2611937,
        "col10": "ABCD",
        "obj4": {
            "col11": "1-1PT-515",
            "col12": "XXXXXXX"
        },
        "col13": 152
    }
}
```

I'm not an expert on json formatting so i have this script in snowflake to flatten this file and obtaining a columnar table with each "colx" as a column and each value as a new row but the performance is really bad

```
select 
    tab1.col1::VARCHAR AS col_1
    ,tab1.col2::VARCHAR AS col_2
    ,tab1.col3::VARCHAR AS col_3
    ,sub1.this:col4::VARCHAR AS col_4
    ,sub1.this:col5::VARCHAR AS col_5
    ,sub1.this:col6::VARCHAR AS col_6
    ,sub2.this:col7::VARCHAR AS col_7
    ,sub2.this:col8::VARCHAR AS col_8
    ,sub3.this:col9::VARCHAR AS col_9
    ,sub3.this:col10::VARCHAR AS col_10
    ,sub4.this:col11::VARCHAR AS col_11
    ,sub4.this:col12::VARCHAR AS col_12
    ,sub3.this:col13::VARCHAR AS col_13
FROM
    DB.SCHEMA.TABLE_1 tab1
    ,lateral flatten(input => obj1) sub1
    ,lateral flatten(input => obj2) sub2
    ,lateral flatten(input => obj3) sub3
    ,lateral flatten(sub3.this:obj4) sub4
GROUP BY ALL;
```

I had to add a "group by all" condition in the end because is generating thousands of rows, for example, with 4.500 rows, generates over 260k repeating each row multiple times,

Thoughts on how to approach this?? I really do hope there's a better way to do this because is taking a lot!

Thanks

Comment: Ah if you know the contents of the array, you don't need to flatten anything.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim what do yo mean? How come?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with this data AND sql you only get one row.

So if we see the the SQL without the GROUP BY:

```
with table_1(j) as (
select parse_json('{
    "col1": 5905,
    "col2": "4540",
    "col3": "23",
    "obj1": {
        "col4": 5905,
        "col5": 3100000000000,
        "col6": null
    },
    "obj2": [
        {
            "col7": null,
            "col8": 1
        },
        {
            "col7": null,
            "col8": 2
        }
    ],
    
    "obj3": {
        "col9": 2611937,
        "col10": "ABCD",
        "obj4": {
            "col11": "1-1PT-515",
            "col12": "XXXXXXX"
        },
        "col13": 152
    }
}')
)
select 
    tab1.j:col1::VARCHAR AS col_1
    ,tab1.j:col2::VARCHAR AS col_2
    ,tab1.j:col3::VARCHAR AS col_3
    ,sub1.this:col4::VARCHAR AS col_4
    ,sub1.this:col5::VARCHAR AS col_5
    ,sub1.this:col6::VARCHAR AS col_6
    ,sub2.this:col7::VARCHAR AS col_7
    ,sub2.this:col8::VARCHAR AS col_8
    ,sub3.this:col9::VARCHAR AS col_9
    ,sub3.this:col10::VARCHAR AS col_10
    ,sub4.this:col11::VARCHAR AS col_11
    ,sub4.this:col12::VARCHAR AS col_12
    ,sub3.this:col13::VARCHAR AS col_13
FROM
    TABLE_1 as tab1
    ,lateral flatten(input => j:obj1) as sub1
    ,lateral flatten(input => j:obj2) as sub2
    ,lateral flatten(input => j:obj3) as sub3
    ,lateral flatten(sub3.this:obj4) as sub4
--GROUP BY ALL
;
```

gives 48 rows:

so given you only have one array, obj2, that should be the only row flattened:

```
with table_1(j) as (
select parse_json('{
    "col1": 5905,
    "col2": "4540",
    "col3": "23",
    "obj1": {
        "col4": 5905,
        "col5": 3100000000000,
        "col6": null
    },
    "obj2": [
        {
            "col7": null,
            "col8": 1
        },
        {
            "col7": null,
            "col8": 2
        }
    ],
    
    "obj3": {
        "col9": 2611937,
        "col10": "ABCD",
        "obj4": {
            "col11": "1-1PT-515",
            "col12": "XXXXXXX"
        },
        "col13": 152
    }
}')
)
select 
    tab1.j:col1::VARCHAR AS col_1
    ,tab1.j:col2::VARCHAR AS col_2
    ,tab1.j:col3::VARCHAR AS col_3
    ,tab1.j:obj1:col4::VARCHAR AS col_4
    ,tab1.j:obj1:col5::VARCHAR AS col_5
    ,tab1.j:obj1:col6::VARCHAR AS col_6
    ,sub2.value:col7::VARCHAR AS col_7
    ,sub2.value:col8::VARCHAR AS col_8
    ,tab1.j:obj3:col9::VARCHAR AS col_9
    ,tab1.j:obj3:col10::VARCHAR AS col_10
    ,tab1.j:obj3:obj4:col11::VARCHAR AS col_11
    ,tab1.j:obj3:obj4:col12::VARCHAR AS col_12
    ,tab1.j:obj3:col13::VARCHAR AS col_13
FROM
    TABLE_1 as tab1
    ,lateral flatten(input => j:obj2) as sub2
;
```

gives:

[image]

Comment: Dude you save me lol, so to fully understand what i'm doing, the flatten only applies when you have not a nested object inside another object but when is an array (inside [] ) right? With the flatten function, snowflake separates, in this case, the to objects that are defined in that array in two separate rows, right?

Comment: FLATTEN can take an Object OR an Array, it will (for ether) loop across the array elements of object elements, you were making a ROW for every permutation of fixed/known object shaped data, and then ignoring the "per rows" (which is accessed via `.VALUE` where-as the `.THIS` is the input to the flatten. So you were making rows, and then asking to have then removed. BUT if your JSON all has the same shape, then it seems you just want N rows for each top level object, where N is the number of elements in the `obj2` array.

Comment: Thanks for checking @SimeonPilgrim - your answer is way better than mine (I'll save that one for a more appropriate time)